# Is possibile to prove the equality $\left(⋃_{X∈\mathfrak X}X\right)×\left(⋃_{Y\in\mathfrak Y}Y\right)=⋃_{(X,Y)∈\mathfrak X×Y}(X×Y)$ using projections?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, alternative-proof

So I know that if $A$ is a subset of a set $X$ and if $X$ is a subset of a set $Y$ then the equalities
$$
\begin{equation}
    \tag{1}\label{1}A\times B=\pi_X^{-1}[A]\cap\pi_Y^{-1}[B]
\end{equation}
$$
holds, **right**?. Moreover, if $\mathfrak X$ and $\mathfrak Y$ are collections then we know that the euqlity
$$
\begin{equation}
    \tag{2}\label{2}\left(\bigcap\mathfrak X\right)\cap\left(\bigcap\mathfrak Y\right)=\bigcap_{(X,Y)\in\mathfrak X\times\mathfrak Y}(X\cap Y)
\end{equation}
$$
holds. Finally if $f$ is a function from a set $H$ to a set $K$ we know that for any collection
$\mathfrak L$ the equality
$$
\begin{equation}
    \tag{3}\label{3}f^{-1}\left[\bigcap\mathfrak L\right]=\bigcap_{L\in\mathfrak L}f^{-1}[L]
\end{equation}
$$
holds.

So I asked to me if using eq. \eqref{1}, eq. \eqref{2} and eq. \eqref{3} is possibile to prove the equality
$$
\begin{equation}
    \tag{4}\label{4}\left(\bigcap_{U\in\mathfrak U}U\right)\times\left(\bigcap_{V\in\mathfrak V}V\right)=\bigcap_{(U,V)\in\mathfrak U\times\mathfrak V}(U\times V)
\end{equation}
$$
where $\mathfrak U$ and $\mathfrak V$ are **arbitrary** collections. So to do this I put
$$
M:=\bigcup\mathfrak U\quad\text{and}\quad N:=\bigcup\mathfrak V
$$
and thus I observed the inclusion
$$
\bigcap\mathfrak U\subseteq M
$$
and the inclusion
$$
\bigcap\mathfrak V\subseteq N
$$
hold so that by \eqref{1}, \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} I argued the equality
$$
\left(\bigcap_{U\in\mathfrak U}U\right)\times\left(\bigcap_{V\in\mathfrak V}V\right)=\pi_M^{-1}\left[\bigcap_{U\in\mathfrak U}U\right]\cap\pi_N^{-1}\left[\bigcap_{V\in\mathfrak V}V\right]=\left(\bigcap_{U\in\mathfrak U}\pi_M^{-1}[U]\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{V\in\mathfrak V}\pi_N^{-1}[V]\right)=\bigcap_{(U,V)\in\mathfrak U\times\mathfrak V}\big(\pi_M^{-1}[U]\cap\pi_N^{-1}[V]\big)=\bigcap_{(U,V)\in\mathfrak U\times\mathfrak V}(U\times V)
$$
since any element of $\mathfrak U$ is a subset of $M$ and since any element of $\mathfrak V$ is a subset of $N$.

Now let be $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ sets so that let's we put
$$
P:=A\cup B\quad\text{and}\quad Q:=C\cup D
$$
so that the inclusion
$$
A,B\subseteq P
$$
and the inclusion
$$
C,D\subseteq Q
$$
holds. So I observed that the equality holds
$$
\begin{equation}
\tag{5}\label{5}
(A\cap B)\times(C\cap D)=\pi_P^{-1}[A\cap B]\cap\pi_Q^{-1}[C\cap D]=\big(\pi_P^{-1}[A]\cap\pi_P^{-1}[B]\big)\cap\big(\pi_Q^{-1}[C]\cap\pi_Q^{-1}[D]\big)=\big(\pi_P^{-1}[A]\cap\pi_Q^{-1}[C]\big)\cap(\pi_P^{-1}[B]\cap\pi_Q^{-1}[D]\big)=(A\times C)\cap(B\times D)
\end{equation}
$$

Now I am quite sure that \eqref{4} holds since it is differently proved in really many texts. However in a text (*Teoria de Conjuntos* by Fernando Hernandez) it is written that \eqref{5} is true surely if $A$ and $B$ are subset of any set $X$ and if $C$ and $D$ are subset of any set $Y$ but into [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_set_identities_and_relations#Binary_%E2%8B%82_of_finite_%E2%A8%AF) wiki article it is said apparently that \eqref{5} generally holds: so if $A$ and $B$ are not contained into a set $X$ and if $C$ and $D$ are not contained into a set $Y$ then this is not evident by more ordinary arguments (e.g. *if $x$ is in $(A\cap B)\times(C\cap D)$ then...*) to me so that I thought I take a mistake and thus I thought to put a question here where I ask if \eqref{5} generally holds and so if I well proved \eqref{4} and \eqref{5} since if \eqref{5} does not holds then it seems to me I do not well proved \eqref{4}. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: @AnneBauval Could I ask you to prove (5) with an alternative arguments? Unfortunately I admit that the fatigue (I am studying by this morning) impedes to do it by myself. Forgive the bother.

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh thanks! thanks really. :-)

Comment: Obviously if you want post an answer I will surely accept it. Thanks yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proofs of (5) and (4) are ok. (5) always hold. Though feasible (as you did when defining $P,Q$), it is useless to consider a set $X$
containing $A$
and $B$
and a set $Y$
containing $C$
and $D$
to prove (5) "by more ordinary arguments":
$$\begin{align}(x,y)\in(A\cap B)\times(C\cap D)&\iff\left((x\in A)\land(x\in B)\right)\land\left((y\in C)\land(y\in D)\right)\\
&\iff\left((x\in A)\land(y\in C)\right)\land\left((x\in B)\land(y\in D)\right)\\
&\iff(x,y)\in(A\times C)\cap(B\cap D).
\end{align}$$