# A question about general associative law for intersection and union.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, definition, alternative-proof

If $\mathfrak F$ is a partition of a collection $\mathcal A$ then it is not hard to show that the equality
$$
\tag{1}\label{eq: general associative law for intersection}\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal A}A=\bigcap_{\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F}\left(\bigcap_{F\in\mathcal F}F\right)
$$
and the equality
$$
\tag{2}\label{eq: general associative law for union}\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}A=\bigcup_{\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F}\left(\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F}F\right)
$$
hold.

Now if $L$, $M$ and $N$ are **mutually** distinct then the collections
$$
\mathfrak U:=\big\{\{L\},\{M,N\}\big\}\quad\text{and}\quad\mathfrak V:=\big\{\{L,M\},\{N\}\big\}
$$
are partition of $\{L,M,N\}$ so that by eq. \eqref{eq: general associative law for intersection} we argue the equality
$$
\tag{3}\label{eq: associative law for intersection with distinct factors}
L\cap(M\cap N)=
\bigcap\big\{L,M\cap N\big\}=
\bigcap\left\{L,\bigcap\big\{M,N\big\}\right\}=\\
\bigcap\left\{\bigcap\big\{L\big\},\bigcap\big\{M,N\big\}\right\}=
\bigcap\left\{\bigcap\big\{L,M\big\},\bigcap\big\{N\big\}\right\}=\\
\bigcap\left\{\bigcap\big\{L,M\big\},N\right\}=
\bigcap\big\{L\cap M,N\big\}=
(L\cap M)\cap N
$$
and by eq. \eqref{eq: general associative law for union} we argue the equality
$$
\tag{4}\label{eq: associative law for union with distinct factors}
L\cup(M\cup C)=
\bigcup\big\{L,M\cup N\big\}=
\bigcup\left\{L,\bigcup\big\{M,N\big\}\right\}=\\
\bigcup\left\{\bigcup\big\{L\big\},\bigcup\big\{M,N\big\}\right\}=
\bigcup\left\{\bigcup\big\{L,M\big\},\bigcup\big\{N\big\}\right\}=\\
\bigcup\left\{\bigcup\big\{L,M\big\},N\right\}=
\bigcup\big\{L\cup M,N\big\}=
(L\cup M)\cup N
$$

Now let be $U$ the set
$$
U:=\big\{\emptyset\big\}
$$
so that let's we put
$$
V:=U\cup\big\{U\big\}\quad\text{and}\quad W:=V\cup\big\{V\big\}
$$
So we observe that $U$, $V$ and $W$ are **mutually** distinct (indeed, for who know the natural numbers $U$ is $1$, $V$ is $2$ and $W$ is $3$) since otherwidse $\emptyset$ would not be empty; moreover, we observe that the inclusive chain
$$
U\subseteq V\subseteq W
$$
holds. Now a not empty (binary) cartesian product is equal to another not empty (binary) cartesian product if the first and the second factor of the first product are respectively equals to the first and second factor of the second product so that if $A$ $B$ and $C$ are not empty then $A\times U$, $B\times V$ and $C\times W$ are distinct and thus by \eqref{eq: associative law for intersection with distinct factors} the equality
$$
\tag{5}(A\times U)\cap\big((B\times V)\cap(C\times W)\big)=\big((A\times U)\cap(B\times V)\big)\cap(C\times W)
$$
holds so that by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4759496/736008) formula we argue the equality
$$
\big(A\cap(B\cap C)\big)\times U=
\big(A\cap(B\cap C)\big)\times(U\cap V)=\\
(A\times U)\cap\big((B\cap C)\times V\big)=
(A\times U)\cap\big((B\cap C)\times(V\cap W)\big)=\\
(A\times U)\cap\big((B\times V)\cap(C\times W)\big)=
\big((A\times U)\cap(B\times V)\big)\cap(C\times W)=\\
\big((A\cap B)\times(U\cap V)\big)\cap(C\times W)=
\big((A\cap B)\times U\big)\cap(C\times W)=\\
\big((A\cap B)\cap C)\times(U\cap W)=
\big((A\cap B)\cap C\big)\times U
$$
and thus by what above observed about equality of not empty (binary) cartesian products we conclude that the equality
$$
\tag{6}\label{eq: associative law for binary intersection}A\cap(B\cap C)=(A\cap B)\cap C
$$

Now we remember that if $H$ and $K$ a respectively two not empty sets of a set $M$ and a set $N$ then the equalities
$$
H=\pi_M[H\times K]\quad\text{and}\quad K:=\pi_N[H\times K]
$$
hold. So let's we put
$$
X:=\bigcup\{A,B,C\}\quad\text{and}\quad Y:=\bigcup\{U,V,W\}
$$
and thus let's we observe the inclusions
$$
A,B,C\subseteq X\quad\text{and}\quad U,V,W\subseteq Y
$$
hold. So if $A\times U$, $B\times V$ and $C\times W$ are mutually distinct then by eq. \eqref{eq: general associative law for union} the equality
$$
\tag{7}(A\times V)\cup\big((B\times V)\cup(C\times W)\big)=\big((A\times V)\cup(B\times V)\big)\cup(C\times W)
$$
holds and thus by what above observed and by "compatibility" of projections with respect union we argue the equality
$$
\tag{8}\label{eq: associative law for binary union}A\cup(B\cup C)=
\pi_X[A\times U]\cup\big(\pi_X[B\times V]\cup\pi_X[C\times W]\big)=\\
\pi_X[A\times U]\cup\pi_X\big[(B\times V)\cup(C\times W)\big]=
\pi_X\Big[(A\times U)\cup\big((B\times V)\cup(C\times W)\big)\Big]=\\
\pi_X\Big[\big((A\times U)\cup(B\times V)\big)\cup(C\times W)\Big]=
\pi_X\big[(A\times U)\cup(B\times V)\big]\cup\pi_X[C\times W]=\\
\big(\pi_X[A\times U]\cup\pi_X[B\times V]\big)\cup\pi_X[C\times W]=
(A\cup B)\cup C
$$

Finally, we observe that if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are empty then \eqref{eq: associative law for binary intersection} and eq. \eqref{eq: associative law for binary union} trivially hold.

So proving eq. \eqref{eq: general associative law for intersection} and eq. \eqref{eq: general associative law for union} I actually observed that it is not necessary for $\mathfrak F$ to be a partition but it is really necessary that $\mathcal A$ is union of $\mathfrak F$ so that in this way the proof of associative law for union and intersection would be more simple. However, I feel that **by an algebraic point of view** it would be better to require that $\mathfrak F$ is a partition so that I thought to put here a specific question where I first ask if I well proved associativity for intersection and union assuming $\mathfrak F$ is a partition and then where I ask some explanation about this hypothesis.

Comment: "So we observe that $U, V$ and $W$ are **mutually** disjoint (indeed, for who know the natural numbers $U$ is $1$, $V$ is $2$ and $W$ is $3$)." (1) they are not disjoint! In fact, $\emptyset \in U \subset V \subset W$. (2) $U, V, W$ play the parts of $1,2,3$ is ONE model of the natural numbers. There are many other models possible. And generally we define the natural numbers to be an *arbitrary* set with certain properties, without giving any specific form for the elements of it.

Comment: I fail to see where you have proved anything. You start off by stating eqns (1) and (2) are easy to prove, but do not offer a proof. Then (3) and (4) are just direct applications of (1) and (2) to the three-set case, and everything else you did started off with (3) and (4), and concluded from it ... (3) and (4)! The purpose of those two quoted discussions completely escapes me.

Comment: **Reply to the first comment** It's a typo: I wanted really say that $U$, $V$ and $W$ are mutually distinct so that even $A\times U$, $B\times V$ and $C\times W$ are mutually distinct.

Comment: **Reply to the second comment** With (3) and (4) I proved that if $L$, $M$ and $N$ are mutually distinct then then the formulas $$L∩(M∩N)=(L∩M)∩N\quad\text{and}\quad L∪(M∪N)=(L∪M)∪N$$ hold. Now $A×U$, $B×V$ and $C×W$ then are distinct  that by (5) I concluded the equality $$\big(A∩(B∩C)\big)×U=\big((A∩B∩C)×U$$ holds and thus projecting I concluded that the equality $$A∩(B∩C)=(A∩B)∩C$$ hold. Finally if $A×U$, $B×V$ and $C×W$ are mutually distinct then by (6) and by "compatibility" of projection with respect union I concluded that the equality $$A∪(B∪C)=(A∪B)∪C$$ hold. Are these arguments wrong?

Comment: You arguments aren't wrong, but the first, proving (3) and (4), is incomplete, since all you did there was apply (1) and (2), which you just proclaimed to be true instead of proving. And the second and third argument start from (3) and (4), and conclude (3) and (4), (relabeling the three arbitrary distinct sets with different letters does not make the conclusion different from the premise). So those arguments appear to be pointless - much ado to arrive at exactly the same place you started.

Comment: I just edited the question: I hope now it is more clear what I done.  However could I ask if you believe it is better or not to require $\mathfrak F$ to be a partition? Anyway thanks for the check. :-)

Comment: I think you should discard (1) and (2), actually prove from first principles (3) and (4). And then that is the end, because all you've done in the rest is make it an even more torturous journey to prove, once again, the very thing that you **already knew** coming in. WHY? What is the purpose of all that when your conclusion $A\cap(B\cap C) = (A\cap B)\cap C$ is just equation (3) again, and your conclusion $A\cup(B\cup C) = (A\cup B)\cup C$ is just equation (4) again? They are not even alternative proofs since you used (3) and (4) to prove them!

Comment: **If $\mathfrak F$ must be a partition** then (3) and (4) -with respect the proof I gave- holds only if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are distinct but this generally do not happens so that the equalities $$A\cap(B\cap C)=(A\cap B)\cap C\quad\text{and}\quad A\cup(B\cup C)=(A\cup B)\cup C$$ must be proved with additional arguments if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are not distinct: is this wrong?

Comment: The issue is that I know that I can prove associativity directly from (1) and (2) since $\mathfrak F$ actually must not to be a partition but I would like to know if I can prove associativity requiring that $\mathfrak F$ must be a partition and then I ask if actually this hypothesis (that about partition) is adopted by other people: is not clear by the question I posed?

Comment: I see, 3 hours ago you dropped the assumption that $A,B,C$ are distinct. So now you actually are proving something slightly different than your start. It is still convoluted and unnecessary, as the formulas when either $A = B, B=C$ or $C = A$ are trivial to prove, since $U \subseteq V \iff U\cap V = U \iff U\cup V = V$. The fact is, you blow off proving (1) and (2) claiming that it is easy. But, it is far easier to prove (3) and (4) for all $L, M, N$ by first principles than (1) or (2), and without any assumptions of distinctness.

Comment: I perfectly know that it is possibile prove ordinary associativity without (1) and (2) but I do not really see how is possibile to prove (1) and (2) with ordinary associativity so that I like to prove ordinary associativity using (1) and (2); finally, the only doubt I have is if it is common to require for $\mathfrak F$ to be a partition and thus I do not prove (1) and (2) since I understood the proof and since this is not what I ask, that's all. I hope now it is clear the goal and the reason of the question.